# How to align these 2 images on the same row?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

So, I can put the 2 images in the same row, but since i wanted to add a subtitle to both images one now stay at the top and the other goes to another line.

Tried pretty much everything now but, I can't align them while i have the subtitle

```
<div class="container row-info">
    <div class="row-fluid ">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-right">
            <figure class="figure">
              <img src="imagens/info.png" class="img-fluid img-info">
                  <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center">Info</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-let">
            <figure class="figure">
                <img src="imagens/idioma.png" class="img-fluid img-idioma">
                <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center">Idioma</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: they might be too wide to fit together in the same line,please provide the code, i'm sure we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your utilizing the col properly. Make sure that all the  in a row equals to 12.  Eg;

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-6">  <img...> </div>
    <div class="col-6">  <img...> </div>
</div>
```

If it's greater than 12, it would spill over below the row.